# HTML Style class with ID?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have a working website that contains a progress bar using Bootstrap. I also have a ID that loads data from a JSON URL in the following format : http://api.bfhstats.com/api/playerInfo?plat=pc&name=1ApRiL&output=js

At the top of my page i have the following code for the progress bar :

```
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"  
style="width: 60%" id="progressbar">60%
</div>
</div>
```

and a script at the bottom :

```
document.getElementById("progressbar").innerHTML = data["player"]["rank"]["next"].relProg+'%';



                }
```

The progress bar fetches the data needed in a string format, so therefore it correctly shows the % from the JSON, however it does not change the style width. The problem is deffinatly within the style tag, and I tried things like

```
style="width: #progressbar"
```

However that doesn't work. Seems strange that the text works, but not actual width.

Comment: When i do that the front of the progress bar vanishes like so : [link](http://i.gyazo.com/394353e23e5695ae6bd009d520353b72.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must manually change the width of the progressbar, using `document.getElementById("progressbar").style.width` after fetching the `percentage` progress data from the server.

To change the style width:

```
var percentage = data["player"]["rank"]["next"].relProg,
    progressbar = document.getElementById("progressbar");

progressbar.innerHTML = percentage+'%';
progressbar .style.width = percentage+'%';
```

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the innerHTML not the style of the element. You may try something like:

```
var x = document.getElementById("progressbar");
x.innerHTML = ....; // change the inner HTML
x.style.width = ...; // change the width...
```

Comment: it's getElementById and not  getElementByID

Answer (score 1):

```
.style.width = data["player"]["rank"]["next"].relProg+'%';
```

make it string if needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
var progressbar = document.getElementById("progressbar");  
var yourWidth = data["player"]["rank"]["next"].relProg+'%';  
progressbar.innerHTML = progressbar.style.width = yourWidth;
```